# Access calendar events remotely on IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, events, calendar, icloud

I am trying to build a server that will get the calendar data from the iPhone so far I made an Xcode project that implement `EKEVentStore` and found out that I can get access to the calendar with that object.

The problem is that I have to open the app to get updates from the calendar, but I want to access remotely. Maybe there is a service from `iCloud` or something else that allow access from a server.

Any help would be appreciated.